# Using different crypto library for server and client

Tags: c#, python, openssl, bouncycastle, ssl

Can different crytographic library be use for server and client?
I want to implement TLS.

Server is currently written in Python; Client is written in C#.

Example, using openssl with m2crypto for client and using Bouncy Castle for Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. They only need to share the same protocol.

Comment: Thanks! Means as long as they follow the structure of the protocol message to be sent out, any libraries can be used. Am I right?

Comment: Not just the same protocol, but also the same set of cipher suites enabled. There are cases when the server and client can't agree on enabled ciphersuites (eg. the server allows only EC suites and the client just doesn't support them).

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the cipher suites!